# How can I get the XAMPP control panel to install & start services correctly?

Tags: mysql, apache, service, xampp

So recently every time I've tried to install Apache/MySQL/FileZilla as a service on XAMPP, it says something along the line of this:

```
5:20:18 AM  [Apache]    Apache Service detected with wrong path
5:20:18 AM  [Apache]    Change XAMPP Apache settings or
5:20:18 AM  [Apache]    Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
5:20:18 AM  [Apache]    Found Path: ERROR: Not Able To Open Service Manager
5:20:18 AM  [Apache]    Expected Path: "f:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
5:20:18 AM  [Apache]    Successful!
```

Afterwards, I can't start the process from the XAMPP panel until I uninstall the service from there and until then the Module name is highlighted red. Although if I leave them installed as a service (red name and all), I can go into the services manager and start them manually and they start fine, and even the XAMPP control panel turns them green and notices they run. This would probably happen for Tomcat as well, I just never use it so I haven't messed with it. All the paths seem to be correct (I do have it on the F drive), but even after countless reinstalls and registry wipe-downs, the XAMPP control does not seem to want to handle installing & running the service correctly. Getting a bit frustrated with this, so thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I reccomend you use wampp instead of xampp. Wampp is more user friendly, and programmer friendly (better error reporting) [WAMPP SITE](http://www.wampserver.com/)

Comment: Does WAMPP include a filezilla server or will I need to set that up seperately?

Comment: You need to set that seperately. but that isn't that hard to do... You can use the filezilla server manager... [link](http://filezilla-project.org/)

But if it's local, then you don't need an ftp server...

Comment: okie doke, thanks. Will give that a shot. And I like to have FTP access to the web files and java files I store here while I'm at work or school.

Comment: I can't seem to access anything on WAMP. I get forbidden message when trying to access any of the apps even after modifying the httpd.conf to allow all and deny none. The localhost root will load, but nothing else it seems.

Comment: alright, i understand :D i love that to. But that ftp server manager is realy good, because it is lightweight, and you can make own users with their own base...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's probably all about privileges, files ACL's etc.

When you start XAMPP in normal mode (not as service) it starts with privileges of user who started it. This is probably your Windows account.

All files owned by your windows account are accessible for XAMPP. So if you create directory "F:\some_dir" it should be accessible for XAMPP in normal mode and there should be no problems, because XAMPP is using your account to access files.

**When application is started as service - it uses another windows account** (there are 2 accounts used by services by default: LOCAL SERVICE, NETWORK SERVICE). **That account probably can't read and write files which belong to your personal windows account**.

**Account used for specyfic service can be changed.** You can run services.msc, select service and go to properties and there should be "Login" tab.

You can also change files/directory permissions and make it available for service account, but i think first solution is better.

Another issue with XAMPP is Control panel, that starts without administrative privileges by default, and it can't control any services, when you starting it from start menu. Some versions of XAMPP after installation will run XAMPP Control Panel with admin privileges, and it works fine until you close that app and start again (without admin privileges).

If you trying to start XAMPP Control Panel and it doesnt ask about admin account - you have to right-click on XAMPP Control Panel icon and click "Run as administrator".

Comment: you my friend have solved my problem... i'm so glad i didn't have to make a question for this. For me the Admin Privileges was needed.. i have been stumped on this for a while now. Thank you @Kamil

Comment: @MasterT Im glad I could help. Note, that this is not exactly about Admin privileges. It worked for you, because Administrator can do everything. You can change read/write privileges for folders and allow writing for normal (non-admin) user.

Answer (score 0):

For the no acces on WAMP server, go to the httpd.conf of appache and then search for something like this:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

But it has then some other values by order and deny.... You must change it to the above to make it work.

Also do i have this in my httpd.conf, mayby you can use that to...:

```
<Directory "D:/wamp_together/www/">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride all

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1

</Directory>
```